# Creating a new document in a Java application

Tags: java, document

I am developing a java application that allow the user to create documents. The program is working fine except that it is closing all the documents when the user clicks the close button on the frame that start to appear when I run the program.

The behavior that I want is similar to MS Word. When you open a new Word Document 1, you can also open new Documents 2,3,4 etc. When a user closes Document 1, the other documents will not be closed as well. However, on my application when I close the Document 1 all the later documents will be closed.

I understand that this is because closing Document 1 in my application will lead to the termination of the `main(String [] args)` method.

Below is the code that is executed when the user click the New Document button.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(count==0){
    if(e.getSource().equals(QuotPane.this.newFile)){
       tablePane=new JTabbedPane();//I have tried to add tabs to the pane but it was overriding the old document
       QuotPane.this.createTablePane();
       tablePane.addTab("New Qout", tablePanel);
       frame.add(tablePane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        count ++;
        }
    }else if(count>0)
    {
    new QuotPane();//creatint a new document here
    }}
```

How do I make it work the way it is done in MS Word?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't do anything with that new object you're creating?  I'd imagine a scenario where you're maintaining a list of these and you simply load whichever one you want to be active.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do a 'mutliple document interface' (mdi) in java is to use a JDesktopPane. Oracle calls this 'internal frames'. It was designed for that purpose.
There is a lot a documentation available in the net (see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).
If you like to checkout a running program you may take a look at my project 'xenia' on github here: https://github.com/gcchris67/Xenia.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to keep other documents open, you can try creating a new Thread per document - and then keep your main() method waiting for all threads to terminate before ending.

Comment: Mind explaining why a thread would make sense in this context?

Comment: To 'make it work like MSWord' I thought the best would be to open a separate window for each document; let a thread handle the document/window; and then have main() exit only once all the threads have terminated (with threads terminating when the document is closed).